# Is it possible to use platform-specific methods of cross-platform sdk in Java?

Tags: java, iphone, android, cross-platform, ipc

is it possible to use functions and methods of an mobile cross-platform sdk, especially MoSync, in Java?

I know about JNI and JNA to solve such problems. But the issue of MoSync is that the compiler produces an intermediate language. This is executed by the runtime environment. In this case I can´t create a DLL because it can´t used without the runtimes.

The reason:
I wan´t to use the communication interface to communicate across plattforms.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MoSync is open source, so you have access to all the code.
AFAIK all the communications protocols are supported.

/Tony